# Convert set date to day of the year

Tags: powershell

I need to get the day of the year from a set date ie. 05/17/2017 to tell me what the day of the year was.

Something somewhat like this (`$b`) only I need it to work.

```
$a = Get-Date
"Day of Year: " + $a.DayOfYear
"date: " + $a

$b = "01/17/2018"
"set date: " + $b
"set day of year: " + $b.DayOfYear
```

Comment: `$b = [DateTime]"01/17/2018"`

Comment: @PetSerAl that did it!

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by using either the PowerShell Cmdlet `Get-Date` or by parsing it using `ParseExact` method of `DateTime`.

```
$date = Get-Date -Date $b;

$template = 'MM/dd/yyyy'
$date = [DateTime]::ParseExact("01/17/2018", $template, $null)
```